# Should I have separate models for EF and the front end (up to the controller level)?

Tags: architecture, domain-model

Models for the database (using EF6) have certain attributes like `Key`, `NotMapped`, or `Required` (which will set the column in SQL Server to `not null`) while models which interact with the MVC portion of the website have their own attributes. An example of that is also `Required` which I use for data validation when a user is submitting a form and which will do fancy things like show error messages on the web page (when I check `Model.IsValid`).

My question is if these two "groups" of method attributes are compatible or should I have one set of models that I use for interaction with EF and another set of models that are used to move data between the Logic/DataAccess layers and the Controller. The idea would be to use something like AutoMapper between the two sets of models.

When necessary, of course, I'll create ViewModels and map whatever I need to those.

Comment: They are compatible, so you can apply everything that matters on the EF properties.  However, there are certain cases where you need an encapsulating object as well.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch What do you mean by "encapsulating object"? Is that something that would hide the attributes and mess up front end validation?

Comment: An example is an index page where you have a list of items.  You'll also need additional properties to control whether you allow a "next page", "previous page" and show "page X of Y" data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute constraints are the least of your problems.  **EF models are not POCO objects**, they are DTO entities which are very tightly inter-twined with your database schema and your `DbContext`/`DbSet`s.

There's a huge amount of invisible logic lurking behind those innocent looking `get` and `set` properties; they (the DTO entities) do all kinds of magical 'EF' things, such as:

- Translate your LINQ-to-Entities queries into SQL
- Handle lazy loading
- EF models are also tied into the `EntityState` for the `DbContext`

Unfortunately, a lot of getting-started ASP.NET MVC tutorials have you putting those models into your controllers.    **Those tutorials are teaching you a really bad habit which will bite you hard as soon as you try to do something non-trivial**

For example, imagine you have an `Employee` EF model, which also has a method in it called `GetManager()`.

See this bit of LINQ, looks innocent right?

```
var managers = from emp in MyDbContext.Employees
               where emp.Department == "Sales"
               select emp.GetManager();
```

if `MyDbContext.Employees` were something simple like a `List<Employee>` where `Employee` is a regular POCO, this would be fine.   but unfortunately the above query will throw an exception because it tries to convert `emp.GetManager()` into a SQL statement - except there is no such thing as `GetManager` in SQL...

Another issue - if you have any lazy-loaded properties which you attempt to use after `DbContext.Dispose()`, you'll find yourself either needing to forcibly load the property before you dispose (and remember to set `EntityState.Detached` too), or performing all of your business logic within your `using` block.

Of course, that might be ok if you have very simple business logic which only cares about a few simple database entities;  you need to keep perspective and remember that KISS is also important.

However, its reasonable to expect you might also need to grab some data from another source, like a file, a network service, another API or other database, etc.   Business logic which happens inside an EF `using` block is a common pathway to technical debt and hard-to-maintain code.

Of course, all of these are things which you can 'work around', but the result is likely to mean mixing all of your UI logic in with your business and data layer logic; separation of UI concerns versus Database concerns becomes awkward when you use EF models in a `Controller`.

So, **be very careful** when deciding to use EF models directly in your MVC Controllers because anything marginally non-trivial can see you fighting all kinds of exceptions thrown by EF which you wouldn't see in regular mapped POCO models.      The price to pay for the nominal amount of extra boilerplate code which maps from your EF models to your 'Business Layer' models is very reasonable, compared with the awful technical debt which you can end up with otherwise.

Comment: I thought there was a way to set up POCOs and have EF bind to it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853(v=vs.100).aspx